# Howto get 'custom web server' working? IIS7.5 VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Error ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830961/sql-server-2008-r2-express-error-asp-net)

When I run a web project in VS2010 I receive the following error (I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on Windows 7):

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
Specified)

It's seems like I found what causes the error, but I have no clue why.

For my website I created a website with some virtual folders and applications. I need an url in my logic. Therefor I use a hostheader (like http://server.name.tld)

In VS2010 I configured Property pages -> start options -> use custom web server with the url (same as the earlier mentioned host header).

If I do that I get the error.

If I use use Property pages -> start options -> default web server, it seems that I get a connection to the db.

But I need the use of the host header.

What do I need to do, to get the 'custom web server' working?

I already made changes in the hosts file (127.0.0.1  http://server.name.tld)

[update]

Anyone knowing good tutorials, sites, books knows about subjects like this (all on the use of host headers, subdomains, host files, dns, etc.). What knowledge is relevant?

[update 2 24-3-2012]

Tried today also with a test virtual machine with windows server 2008. Still getting the error.

Also made a test web application, without an IIS site an without a host-header. That one works just fine (using the same connectstring). Also on the VM.

I am lost. I really need someone who can exchange some knowledge to me in this field ...

Comment: This issue is related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830961/sql-server-2008-r2-express-error-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

## red cheeks

Found the problem. Web.config configured with a session db, but no session db created and wasn't planning any longer to do so. Forget to turn it off ...